# A strange Modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

When trying to determine the relators of a subgroup of a fp group I bumped on this equation, that I verified for some dozen primes $p$:
$$p^q(p+1)^{p^2}\mod p^4 = p^q$$ for $q \in \{1,2,3\} $. I briefly tought to develop the binomial but this seems unfeasable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can work as follows:

$$p^q(p+1)^{p^2}-p^q=p^q\left[(p+1)^{p^2}-1\right]$$

But

$$(p+1)^{p^2}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{p^2}\binom{p^2}kp^k-1=\sum_{k=1}^{p^2}\binom{p^2}kp^k$$

and now observe that $\;p^2\,\mid\mid\binom{p^2}k\;\iff p^2\,\nmid\,k\;$ , and $\;p\,\mid\mid\binom{p^2}k\iff p\,\mid\,k\;$ , so we get

$$\binom{p^2}{mp}p^{mp}=p\cdot R\cdot p^{mp}=Rp^{pm+1}\;,\;\;R\in\Bbb N$$

and $\;pm+1< 4\implies p<\frac3m\le 3\;$ , so if $\;p\;$ is an odd prime we're done, and if $\;p=2\;$ then directly

$$2^q\cdot\left(3^{2^2}-1\right)=2^q\cdot80=0\pmod{2^4}$$

Comment: 1) What is the meaning of $\;p^2\,\mid\mid\binom{p^2}k$ ?  2) WHy is $pp^{mp} = p^{p(m+1)}$ instead of $p^{mp+1}$? 3) What happened to $p^q$; the equation is false for $q = 0, q = 4,5,6,\ldots$.

Comment: @BogaertsMarc Sorry, perhaps that symbol isn't as standard as I thought. It means that $\;2\;$ is the maximal power of $\;p\;$ that divides the right side. In general, we write $\;a^n\,\mid\mid\,b\iff a^n\,\mid b\;\;\text{and}\;\;a^{n+1}\,\nmid b\;$ . For example, $\;2^4\,\mid\mid\,80\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntronio Oops, I was editing my comment (pushed return by accident) after I already composed my first quetion...

Comment: That $\;p(m+1)\;$ instead of $\;pm+1\;$ is a mistake I made, I think because I typed ( by mistake and didn't pay attention. I shall edit that now. Thanks. Oh, and it doesn't affect the gist, I believe.